# Unwanted messages every time I attempt to login?

Tags: error-handling

I am using Linux Mint Olivia and it worked fine for past couple of months but from yesterday it keep showing these message whenever I want to login to my PC:

> Keys: Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery

If I press <kbd>s</kbd>, then it shows another message:

> Keys: Continue to wait , or press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery

If I press <kbd>s</kbd>, then it allows me to login.

Can any one tell me how can I login normally?

Contents of my `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=e1867541-6f11-4fd8-8121-2318248cb9c4 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1 
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation 
UUID=8f655fe6-92c5-43c8-9655-2c2b3485a836 none swap sw 0 0
UUID=[C59C-D751] /media/[bappu] vfat user,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=027,fmask=137 0 0
```

Comment: Show us the contents of your /etc/fstab.

Comment: UUID=e1867541-6f11-4fd8-8121-2318248cb9c4 /               ext4  <br>  

errors=remount-ro 0       1 <br>
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=8f655fe6-92c5-43c8-9655-2c2b3485a836 none            swap    sw              0       0<br>

UUID=[C59C-D751]  /media/[bappu] vfat user,uid=1000,gid=100,dmask=027,fmask=137  0  0

Comment: Do/did you have an external storage disk formatted with FAT? Is it connected/working? I'd say that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are failing to mount a drive. Either because it's broken or because it's removable. From your fstab I would say /media/[bappu] isn't plugged in. I would recommend adding 'noauto' to your fstab line.